# .NET collection that throws an exception when a duplicate is added

Tags: .net, collections, unique, duplicates

Is there a collection (apart from Dictionary) in the .NET framework (3.5) that throws an exception when a duplicate is added?

HashSet does not throw an exception here:

```
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>();
strings.Add("apple");
strings.Add("apple");
```

Whereas the Dictionary does:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("dude", "dude");
dict.Add("dude", "dude"); //throws exception
```

EDIT: Is there a collection without (Key, Value) that does this? I also want AddRange if possible...

I rolled my own:

```
public class Uniques<T> : HashSet<T>
{

    public Uniques()
    { }

    public Uniques(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        AddRange(collection);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!base.Add(item))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Item already exists");
        }
    }


    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see your edit, I'm deleting my original answer. To answer your edit, no.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the 'new' keyword to the 'Add' method signature, for it hides the inherited member HashSet<T>.Add(T).

Comment: why dont you add extension methods to HashSet<T> ?
like AddRange/RemoveMany  will be like Linq (like saying 'Linq')

Answer (score 19, accepted):

But the HashSet.Add method returns false if the value already is present - isn't that enough?

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
...
if (!set.Add("Key"))
    /* Not added */
```

Comment: It allows you to add without the cost of checking Contains before, two operations in one call. There is no TryAdd on the Dictionary<,>.

Comment: I prefer it but it's strange as ICollection.Add returns void and others collection that disallow duplicates throw...

Comment: Ok, I sort of wanted AddRange functionality. Thanks

Comment: Oops... it does indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `AddRange` style functionality, look at [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5). The collections in the C5 family have a lot more functionality exposed in their interfaces, including a function `AddAll` that takes an enumerable, adding all the items in the enumerable to the collection in turn.

EDIT: Also note that the `C5` collections implement the `System.Collections.Generic` `ICollection` and `IList` interfaces where appropriate, so can be used as the implementation even in systems that expect those interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Bjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64495/bj%c3%b6rn)'s answer, if you also want a function like `IList.AddRange` type of function with `HashSet<T>`, you can use `HashSet<T>.UnionWith` ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097(v=vs.110).aspx)):

### HashSet(T).UnionWith Method

> Modifies the current HashSet object to contain all elements that are present in itself, the specified collection, or both.

```
public void UnionWith(
    IEnumerable<T> other
)
```

Only problem might be: I'm pretty sure this requires the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and up.